# Displaying error message without postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got this an asp.net 3.5 page that and I have few tabs (telerik tabs control with pageview) and I have panel on the top of the page and inside that has a label control displaying error message if it's any.

At the moment, if I want to display this, at the end of the event clicked button for instance, I have to do a custom URL redirection class to itself passing error message and display the error. BUT the problem with this approach let say you are working on 4th tabs and you click save button inside this then you loose the state of series of control (what's is being choosed, selected, typed etc). The page refreshed and displayed at the first tab again.

I want to display the error and at the same time know the state is for every control on the 4th tabs and automatically goes to 4th tabs. BTW ... this validation is done through server level.

I am appreciated your feedback/suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several approaches here:

1. Make an ajax call with data to validate and show error message basing on its result.
2. Recover your control state after post back, you will need to write some client logic that will analyze url for some parameter after "#", e.g. http://my-site.com/tabs.aspx#4. Your script will know that you need 4-th tab.
3. You can try to recover your control state on the server, but I don't know how it is possible with telerick tab control.

Comment: or implement the validation directly in the JS, if you can.

Comment: The validation needs to be done on the server due to involving back end stuff

Comment: 1n regards to #3, can you elaborate a bit more on this?

Comment: Sure, you just need to re-bind your control with data on the server-side, and "say" it to show tab number 4, I don't know whether it is possible in telerik control, but you can try.